# Hibernate's setFirstResult() issue with Oracle jdbc driver

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I'm trying to do pagination with Hibernate using `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` but I'm not getting the expected results when setting the first result to 0.

When doing the following:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);  
query.setFirstResult(0);  
query.setMaxResults(30);  
List list = query.list();  //list.size() returns 10
```

but if I set the first result to 1 (or anything different than 0 for that matter):

```
query.setFirstResult(1);  
query.setMaxResults(30);  
List list = query.list();  //list.size() returns 30
```

I read this is a known bug in the jdbc driver, but I searched for a solution and I can't seem to find it. Has anyone run across anything similar and found a fix for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently adding `setFetchSize()` does the trick. So something like this now works perfectly:

```
query.setFirstResult(0);  
query.setMaxResults(30);  
query.setFetchSize(30);  
List list = query.list(); //list.size() now returns... wait for it... 30
```

Comment: You wonderful man! I just had this exact problem and `setFetchSize()` fixed it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution is to implement your own Oracle Dialect:

```
public class Oracle10gDialectLimitBugfix extends Oracle10gDialect {
    @Override
    public boolean forceLimitUsage() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

See https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2379096

UPDATE: It seems to be fixed in Oracle 11.2.0.1.0